# Reference to object not same as the object?

Tags: javascript, html

Why this works:

```
var i = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChid(i);
```

But not this:

```
var i = document.createElement("input");
var f = document.body.appendChild;
console.log(f === document.body.appendChild); //outputs true
f(i);
```

And the error details is:

```
TypeError: 'appendChild' called on an object that does not implement interface Node.
```

Comment: In the first snippet, you're calling `document.body.appendChild`; in the second, you're trying to call `document.appendChild`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that was. Thanks for notifying. But the question persists. why doesn't work?

Comment: if you want to use `f(i)` to do `document.body.appendChid(i)` you can do this by `var f = function(n){return document.body.appendChid(n)}` also you can use `var f = new Function('return document.body.appendChid(n)')`

Comment: Then I'm guessing the problem is that  `this` differs between the two calls -- if you're invoking `appendChild` as a method, it'll reference `document.body`; as a bare function call it'll be `undefined` if you have `use strict` up.  Try `f.call(document.body, i)`.

Comment: @MattOlson when the '===' returns true it means the operands are same type with same variable so they are same reference to a same object. in other words they are identical and same thing should happen. But I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: @CS It's because you're invoking the function differently in each case.  One is a method call (on the object `document.body`), one is a bare call (through the reference `f`).  They behave differently, even though they're calling the same object.

Comment: @MattOlson Seems this is how javascript "calling" functions works... It checks where and how the method is called and assigns or considers corresponding properties. These confusions happens because of huge difference between JS and most other languages like C and java itself which I always coded in. And the difference is often in the way JS interprets objects or OOP.

Comment: @CS Yes, exactly.  JS functions get called with `this` and `arguments` as hidden parameters (unless you make them explicit through `fn.call` or `fn.apply`), and how `this` is set varies by how you invoke the function.

Comment: @MattOlson Yes right. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, what looks like a "method" doesn't actually "know" what object it's attached to; essentially, it's just a function which happens to have been saved as a property of some object. The determination of what object `this` will represent happens when you call it, in most circumstances based on the object to the left of the `.` in the call.

So your variable `f` points at the right function, but when it's called, it will see the wrong value of `this`. Since in this case it expects to be called on a DOM Node (in the working test, `document.body`), calling it outside of that scope raises the error shown.

Note that the above is all slightly simplified, with just enough detail to explain your example. You can probably find further reading by searching for explanations of `this` as well as `call` and `apply`, which are ways of  explicitly setting the `this` binding of a function call.